# .NET Core - VSTS Release - wrong aspNetCore .exe path

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, path, web-config

I have to manualy change the web.config file every time to adapt for the path of my executable file

**the config on my dev computer is not the same as on the destination machine**

I read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic

but variable substitution appear to only be working with keys, not with tags attributes

how can I change  processPath value in this case ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="C:\WORK\ANGULAR\...\MyApp.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="443" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

anyone already had the same issue ?

thanks for your time

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? I've updated the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

1.[Magic Chunks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergeyzwezdin.magic-chunks) can be suitable for your scenario.

Use `transformations` like `"configuration/location/system.webServer/aspNetCore/@processPath": "new path"` and then you can overwrite the `processPath` in release without affecting source control. (This extension still works currently though it's last updated in 2018)

[image]

2.Also, you can consider overwriting whole xml content with [File Creator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eliostruyf.build-task) extension so that you won't need to worry about the transform syntax.

[image]

They both support variables when transforming the config files.

Comment: the problem is that my project wont work localy anymore...the processPath has to be correct on my pc

Comment: @phil123456 I've just updated my answer with your requirements...Let me know if it works for you. PS: They both won't affect your Git Source Control~